# Can I use a local repository as a git remote

Tags: git

I have two repositories locally, A and B. Can I use the local copy of A, as a remote in B?

Something like

```
git remote add A file:///path/to/repo/
```

Comment: If you cloned one from the other, you also probably want to use the `--no-hardlinks` flag. Otherwise the clone hardlinks the origin.

Comment: Good hint. (I guess, there wouldn't be any side effects though?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yep, works like a charm.

```
git remote add A file:///path/to/repo/
```

Comment: I actually tried this before I posted, sorry for getting the order wrong in the q. While A shows up in B's `git remote -v' list, I can't see A's branches in B with `git branch -a`.

Comment: You must issue a `git fetch A` first. (`git pull A` does so implicitly.)